# Cannot receive data by a socket from a device (in WLAN) via UDP

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, wifi

my android device is connected to my home-wireless-network. Also a special UDP-device is connected to it. My android app successfully can send commands to the UDP-device. But if I open a socket it does not receive data. Can you see what is wrong? I know the ip of the UDP-device from the iphone-APP which is working

Here is how the app send commands:

```
public static final String SERVERIP = "192.168.2.114";
public static final int PORT = 44444;
public void run() {
    try {
        serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
        byte[] buf = message.toByteArray();
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length,     serverAddr, PORT);
        socket.send(packet);
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("UDP", "Sender/Client: Error", e);
    }
}
```

Whereas I have two approaches for receiving data:

```
public static final String SERVERIP = "192.168.2.114";
public static final int SERVERPORT = 44445;

private InetAddress serverAddr;

public void run() {
    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(SERVERPORT, serverAddr);
        byte[] buf = new byte[65213];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        socket.receive(packet);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("UDP", "Receiver: Error", e);
    }

    try {
        serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
        DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
        DatagramSocket socket = channel.socket();
        byte[] buf = new byte[65213];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length,     serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
        socket.receive(packet);
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("UDP", "Sender/Client: Error", e);
    }
}
```

The approach in the first try block leads to an exception:

```
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.bind(Native Method)
at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.bind(BlockGuard.java:268)
at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:81)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.createSocket(DatagramSocket.java:193)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:95)
at de.myappname.connection.Receiver.run(Receiver.java:29)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

The second approach just blocks the thread by socket.receive(packet) which does not receive data. From the iphone and specification I know the device sends data via UDP 44445 over WLAN. Any suggestions what is wrong? 
Thank you!

Comment: Finally found the solution here: http://code.google.com/p/boxeeremote/wiki/AndroidUDP

Answer (score 1):

UDP port 44445 is used by eMule protocol. Do you have any other eMule clients active on your device?

**Update:**

The problem seems to be the address you bind to - it must be an address on the localhost, i.e. IP address of your device, not remote device. See [`DatagramSocket(port, InetAddress)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#DatagramSocket%28int,%20java.net.InetAddress%29) constructor.

Comment: Edited - there seem to be a problem with the IP address.

Comment: Actually there I killed all apps in the taskkiler. There is no app that might listen hrough 44445. What might be wrong about the IP adress? Especially when sending data is working.

Comment: Ok, so what can I do then to receive data from the UDP-device on 192.168.2.114? Why binding works when I send data then?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to put the receive() function inside a while loop since you current code looks like it receives message only once; it doesn't guarantee that it will contain any valid data.

Comment: I put it in a while-loop but still the command is blocking, so that the loop does not even get in the second iteration.